# Joomla component Ajax call : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla, joomla3.0

I am quite a newbie in Joomla and Javascript and JQuery.
I am writing a Joomla 3.x component and trying to use an Ajax call in a backend form.

I have written an Ajax call to update some fields on the fly in my edit.php (see the code below). I have attached a big part of the code as I am wondering if I am messing up with the javascript, Jquery and the Joomla stuff ...

And I get the following error at runtime on chrome : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at the line method: "POST", of my Ajax call.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you very much for the time you spend on my question.

Best regards

Eric

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  com_emc
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2015 Eric LLANO. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

JHtml::_('jquery.framework');

JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');
JHTML::_('behavior.modal'); 

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.noConflict();

    function checkAmount() {
        //billable_items_table = document.getElementById("#jform_billable_items_table_table");
        console.log( "Table modified" );
        //alert(billable_items_table.value);
    }

    function calculateAmount() {
        billable_items_table =  document.getElementById("jform_billable_items_table_table");
        //
        console.log( "Table saved" );
        alert(billable_items_table.value);      
    }

    function calculateVAT() {
        console.log( "VAT modified" );
        calculateVATAjax();
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        console.log( "ready!" );

        function calculateVATAjax() {
            var taxable =           document.getElementById("jform_taxable");
            var amount_exc_VAT =    document.getElementById("jform_amount_exc_VAT");

            jQuery.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "index.php?option=com_emc&task=invoice.calculateVAT&format=json",
                data: { taxable: taxable.value,
                        amount_exc_VAT: amount_exc_VAT.value,
                        <?php  echo(JSession::getFormToken());?>: 1
                    },
                success: function(r) {
                    if (!r.success && r.message) {
                        // Success flag is set to 'false' and main response message given
                        // So you can alert it or insert it into some HTML element
                        alert(r.message);
                    }

                    if (r.messages) {
                        // All the enqueued messages of the $app object can simple be
                        // rendered by the respective helper function of Joomla!
                        // They will automatically be displayed at the messages section of the template
                        Joomla.renderMessages(r.messages);
                    }

                    document.getElementById("jform_VAT_rate").value = r.data.VATrate;
                    document.getElementById("jform_VAT_amount").value = r.data.VAT_amount;
                    document.getElementById("jform_amount_inc_VAT").value = r.data.amount_inc_VAT;
                    //if (r.data)
                    //{
                        // Here you can access all the data of your response
                        //alert(r.data);

                    //}
                },
                failure: function(xhr) {
                    // Reaching this point means that the Ajax request itself was not successful
                    // So JResponseJson was never called
                    alert('Ajax error');
                },
                error: function(text, error) {
                    // Reaching this point means that the Ajax request was answered by the server, but
                    // the response was no valid JSON (this happens sometimes if there were PHP errors,
                    // warnings or notices during the development process of a new Ajax request).
                    alert("Ajax request was answered by the server"+"\n"+error + "\n" + text);
                }
            });
        }

        // Add the event handlers
        $("#jform_taxable").change(calculateVAT);
        $("#jform_billable_items_table_table").change(checkAmount);
        $(".save-modal-data").click(calculateAmount);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I definitely think you will get more help at [joomla.se].

Comment: Do you mean I should add the Joomla tag to my question?

Comment: No follow that link to the joomla stackexchange site.